# sources: where daemon call libcontainer in createContainer

Tags: docker

I found daemon create a container by these code

```
// NewBaseContainer creates a new container with its
// basic configuration.
func NewBaseContainer(id, root string) *Container {
    return &Container{
        CommonContainer: CommonContainer{
            ID:            id,
            State:         NewState(),
            ExecCommands:  exec.NewStore(),
            Root:          root,
            MountPoints:   make(map[string]*volume.MountPoint),
            StreamConfig:  runconfig.NewStreamConfig(),
            attachContext: &attachContext{},
        },
    }
}
```

It looks like create a instance but just some config. I don't know where it call the libcontainer to create the real container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code actually comes from [`container/container.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e2133b42ffc76d86809048cd87de50ad1b7f082d/container/container.go#L101-L115).
You would have to go back to docker 1.9.0 to find that code actually still in [`daemon/daemon_windows.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.9.0/daemon/daemon_windows.go#L143-L152)

A new daemon [is setup with a libcontainerd](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/daemon.go#L451-L453), in order to create the actual container (in docker 1.10 or more)